# type of process dump when its generated from task manager

Tags: windows, windbg, crash-dumps, taskmanager, adplus

Starting from Windows Vista, now one can generate a process dump right from task manager. Typically I generate a process dump either by using Adplus or right from Windbg. If I use one of these option, I have to provide some switches with my command in order to describe what type of dump is been generated. Given that all these details are hidden when I generate a process dump from task manager, does someone know what type of dump it is and what is contained in it? I remember reading somewhere that process dump generated from task manager does not contains details on the handle table. Any ideas on this as well?

Comment: It is a big one, kit and caboodle included.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dump is a "User Mini Dump File with Full Memory", so for most tasks you're good.

However, you can't specify that the dump should be created at some specific event. Tools like adplus and procdump allow you to create a dump for various conditions (exception, work load etc). So essentially task manager only supports give me a snapshot of the process (which is usable for a hanging process). For other situations you need to use adplus or procdump.

Also, you should be aware that 64 bit Windows ships with two versions of the task manager. The 64 bit manager will create 64 bit dumps - even for 32 bit processes (i.e. the dump will contain the Wow64 stuff needed to run the 32 bit process). However, if you use the 32 bit version of task manager (located in \Windows\SysWOW64) you'll get a proper 32 bit dump.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your response. My question is really about type of dump gnerated via task manager. Is it something like .dump /ma or is it .dump /mt or something else etc.  One thing I have noticed in analyzing dump file generated via task manager is that I don't get anything when I run !handle command. I assumed that it probably because dump does not have handle data

Comment: It generates a "User Mini Dump File with Full Memory" which should be the same as the .dump /ma command. However, I just verified that I don't get any data for !handle either. Interesting (too bad I can't upvote your question again ...)

Comment: atleast its re-assuring that i am not crazy :) I guess its still a mystery why mini dump with full memeory does not include handle table